# Upgrade SSO database, can we avoid reconfiguration?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

We are on BizTalk 2013 Enterprise, we just noticed that the SSO database was accidentally deployed to SQL Server 2008 instead of SQL 2012 (where all other databases is), question is can we just take the database from SQL 2008 restore it on SQL 2012 and update BizTalk management database to point there instead of reconfigure BizTalk, redeploy and risk the application outage? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes.**
You would follow the procedures documented here: [Moving BizTalk Server Databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559835(v=bts.20).aspx)

In your case, you would only move the SSODB and follow the restore instructions for SSODB only.